Remove no usages in IntelliJ IDEA
is possible remove "no usages" taged code by IntelliJ on save actions ?

Example this code.

Peace!

To turn off the inlay hint, shown in the second image:

Open the Settings, and go to Editor | Inlay hints.
Under Code Vision, turn off Usages.


I mean, deleting all the code, not only the Tag "Usages".
